# How might you identify eth addresses with the same owner?

Tags: transactions, addresses, address.transfer

Given an ethereum address, how might you identify (or make a good guess) as to which other ethereum addresses belong to the same owner?

Note: I'd come across some content that somewhat answers this question in the context of bitcoin but not ethereum.  The bitcoin approaches I'd come across were mostly bitcoin-specific (eg take advantage of bitcoin's input/output transaction structure).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to track the total amount of ETH being sent out of an address.  Assuming you know one address of a particular person - you can track what other addresses they are sending ETH and other tokens to.  Right now not many people are making large ETH transactions so you could probably safely assume that a person is spreading the ETH among a few wallets for security reasons.

Also - there are alot of cool identity management projects in the works that are focusing on this.  One with alot of traction is uPort.  I dont know if this will give you the balances of a particular user but it sounds like you question is around identity management.